# Facebook ShareLinkContent not showing preview of image in dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to do something:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.101campaigns.com"))
                        .setContentTitle(SocialMediaModel.getInstance().getSharedTitle())
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(SocialMediaModel.getInstance().getCampaignImageUrl()))
                        .setContentDescription(SocialMediaModel.getInstance().getSharedContent())
                        .build();
                shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

[image]

In my android app, but when the dialogue appears for preview it does not show image as preview on left side, any one guide me what is the problem? i dont find this problem on google and else where on facebook developer portal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a detail investigation i come to know facebook dont pickup thumbnail from ip address so my image was having ip address like

[enter link description here](http://192.168.1.1/abc/my.jpg)  (that's why it was not working)

But when i shifted it to actual domain

[``](http://www.testingdomain.com/abc/my.jpg)  (it started showing)

Posting answer will might be helpful for anyone else.

Thank you!